# Can I call Greenshot on a client's machine from a website?

Tags: c#, screenshot

I am looking to make Greenshot take an IE screen shot from the code behind of a C# Web Form. How can I call Greenshot from my server or code running in the browser and have it take a screenshot on the client's machine?

Comment: Is the web-application running locally on the same computer? If not, then it's impossible because the interface between web-server and web-browser is only HTML (and JavaScript) and there is no provision for controlling other client-side components that way - unless you want to use a browser extension or ActiveX control, and even then there's a sandbox you're stuck in.

Comment: @Dai I would have put that as an answer :)

Comment: This is not even a question. It's a statement of intent at best.

Comment: @Dai It's also worth mentioning that if the server account has permissions on the client's computer (such as within a business network) the server can execute *any* code it wants on the client machine. It won't be via normal web protocols though. Probably not too secure, and something to avoided. But it's something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code behind of a web form (or really, any code behind in ASP) is run *on the server*. The server cannot *directly* run code on a client (it can, of course, inject javascript into its responses).

So no, you won't be able to do this in the manner you describe. However, if a given page had JS that performed this task for you on page load (or on a button click, or whatever), you could likely get a similar result.

Looking at Greenshot it looks like that is a program that is run on the client's computer, so this is even *more* impossible as the browser sandbox isn't going to let JavaScript run that application. There are possibly other ways to get an image of the rendered content in JavaScript, but that approach seems very unlikely to work.